# Can I call the android contact picker and force it to start using portrait orientation?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I know how to force the orientation on my activities (Using the xml layout or programatically).

But can I force the contact picker to start in Portrait mode?

I call the contactPicker using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_PICKER_REQ_CODE);
```

Comment: Development questions are off topic here. Please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But can I force the contact picker to start in Portrait mode?

No. The developer of that app will handle portrait versus landscape how that developer wanted it handled.